# Premature setTimeout execution

Tags: javascript

I have a script which should to check user activity on a browser window (mouse and keyboard) and if there is no activity after 5 minutes execute logout function.

Simple functionality code looks like:

```
var tempLOT = 300000;

console.log('Auto Logout: ' + tempLOT + ' ms');

var st = new Date().toLocaleTimeString();
console.log('Auto Refresh started: ' + st);

document.onload = function() {
    inactivityTime();
};
document.onmousedown = function() {
    inactivityTime();
};
document.onkeypress = function() {
    inactivityTime();
};
document.ontouchstart = function() {
    inactivityTime();
};

var inactivityTime = function () {

    var t;
    window.onload = resetTimer;
    document.onmousemove = resetTimer;
    document.onkeypress = resetTimer;


    function LOT() {
        console.log("Time to log out");
    }

    function resetTimer() { 

        clearTimeout(t);
        t = setTimeout(LOT, tempLOT);

        var dateObj = Date.now();

        dateObj = dateObj + tempLOT;
        estLOT = new Date(dateObj);

        var ot = new Date().toLocaleTimeString();   
        console.log("Ongoing User Activity: " + ot);
        console.log("Activity Counter: " + t);
        console.log("Estimated LOT: " + estLOT);

    }
};
```

Code works fine when I have `tempLOT` below 5 minutes. Anything else got executed prematurely. Below output from the console:

```
Auto Logout: 300000 ms
(index):1 Auto Refresh started: 10:58:08 AM
(index):1 Ongoing User Activity: 10:58:21 AM
(index):1 Activity Counter: 223
(index):1 Estimated LOT: Fri Sep 30 2016 11:03:21 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)
(index):1 Ongoing User Activity: 10:58:22 AM
(index):1 Activity Counter: 226
(index):1 Estimated LOT: Fri Sep 30 2016 11:06:57 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)
[...] ----------- more user activity here ------
---------------- User left browser window ------------------------
---------- Then user come back to a browser window ---------------
(index):1 Ongoing User Activity: 11:04:01 AM
(index):1 Activity Counter: 8054
(index):1 Estimated LOT: Fri Sep 30 2016 11:09:01 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)
(index):1 Ongoing User Activity: 11:04:01 AM
(index):1 Activity Counter: 8056
[...] ------- more user activity here ------
(index):1 Ongoing User Activity: 11:04:07 AM
(index):1 Activity Counter: 8703
(index):1 Estimated LOT: Fri Sep 30 2016 11:09:07 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)
(index):1 Ongoing User Activity: 11:04:07 AM
(index):1 Activity Counter: 8705
(index):1 Estimated LOT: Fri Sep 30 2016 11:09:07 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)
(index):1 Ongoing User Activity: 11:04:07 AM
(index):1 Activity Counter: 8707
(index):1 Estimated LOT: Fri Sep 30 2016 11:09:07 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)
(index):1 Auto Refresh stopped: 11:04:21 AM
(index):1 Time to log out
```

Based on user activity logout should occur at 11:09:07 GMT but were executed at 11:04:21.

Any clue what is going on?

Comment: Afaik `document` doesn't fire `onload` event.

Comment: @Teemu should I switch to `window`? But I think this is not a case for premature execution.

Comment: setTimeout is not accurate

Comment: @epascarello not accurate by that function functionality?

Comment: problem is where you define `t`

Comment: @epascarello what is the problem there? It sets `t` as `setTimeout` to execute `LOT` function  after `tempLOT` time

Comment: You can't set two listeners with a listener property. You'd need to use `addEventeListener` instead. You probably need [`DOMContentLoaded`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded) for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You define `t` inside of `inactivityTime` so every time you call it you declare a new `t` so the other timer will still exist. Also why are you rebinding all those events inside of it?

Your code really should just be

```js
(function() {

  var t,
    timeout = 5000;

  function resetTimer() {
    console.log("reset: " + new Date().toLocaleString());
    if (t) { 
      window.clearTimeout(t); 
    }
    t = window.setTimeout(logout, timeout);
  }

  function logout() {
    console.log("done: " + new Date().toLocaleString());
  }
  resetTimer();

  //And bind the events to call `resetTimer()`
  ["click", "mousemove", "keypress"].forEach(function(name) {
    console.log(name);
    document.addEventListener(name, resetTimer);
  });

}());
```

```html
<p>TEST</p>
```

Comment: To reset the counter. So what is correct fix for that code?

Comment: Replaced mine whole code with yours and got an error: `Unexpected end of input`

Comment: Not sure what happened when you copied and pasted it.

Comment: Just replaced mine code with yours. Is this pure JS or jQuery is involved in that code example  execution? When I remove `(function() {` and `}());` it works but only once

Comment: When I remove `(function() {` and `}());` it works but only once so it must be something with declaration of that function.

Comment: All that is doing is keeping the variables from going into global scope. It should work fine with it. The code should only run once, initialize when the code is run, and the event handlers call the reset. You can bind any events you want and you can do it on window instead of document.

Comment: Found an issue -  somehow code "doesn't like" `//` as a comment (is based on Knockout JS)